# Why SPI sequence doesnt match MSB order EFR32

Tags: embedded

I am sending a sequence as shown bellow  MSB first order,using SPI.
When i look at the sequence displayed on osciloscope shown bellow, i see 111 from the left end and 11 from the right end it doesnt match the sequence i am sending .
the attached  code shown bellow.
Where did i go wrong?
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

```
uint8_t Tx_WRSR[TX_WRSR_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x01,0x2F,0xEF,0xD8}; //write status register

           USART1->IEN = USART_IEN_TXC; //enable TXC interrupt flag

         while(1)
     {
            Delay(1);
               GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortA,4);
              USART_Tx(USART1, Tx_WRSR[0]);
               while( !(USART1->STATUS & USART_STATUS_TXC) );  //wait TILL TXC goes high
              USART_Tx(USART1, Tx_WRSR[1]);
               while( !(USART1->STATUS & USART_STATUS_TXC) );  //wait TILL TXC goes high
                USART_Tx(USART1, Tx_WRSR[2]);
                while( !(USART1->STATUS & USART_STATUS_TXC) );  //wait TILL TXC goes high
                USART_Tx(USART1, Tx_WRSR[3]);
               while( !(USART1->STATUS & USART_STATUS_TXC) );  //wait TILL TXC goes high
              GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortA,4);
             Delay(1);

            }

}
```

Comment: You aren't using SPI. You are using UART (similar to RS-232). UART also sends a start and a stop bit for each byte. The start bit is usually low, the stop bit is high. That's already much closer to what you are seeing on the oscilloscope though not fully consistent yet.

Comment: This is to say your USART is probably configured for asynchronous, RS-232 compatible mode instead of synchronous SPI mode.

Comment: Here's your oscilloscope screenshot with an [overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiJ0M.jpg) of what I think the USART generates. The yellow bits match your data, the blue bits are some sort of start and stop bits (but not consistent with RS-232).

Comment: @Codo Uart idles high as well. Step 1 here is for the OP to figure out what they are even doing... if they can't tell the difference between SPI and UART, then there can be no correct result.